# JAVA button inside a frame generates chart

Tags: java, swing, button, charts, frame

it's my first post here but desperate times require desperate moves. My problem is that I've made a JFrame with buttons and others that does my project (every next button shows when the previous one is clicked (code consists on *if* and *else*). When the penultimate button (the last one *else*) is clicked it does the last part od the project and shows, let's call it, "Create Chart" button. What I want do is to have new frame being showed after clicking this button that will show a chart in a new frame. Here's my code (shortened and simplified just to show the idea):

```
public class clazz extends JFrame
{
    static JButton // my buttons
    static JLabel //my labels
    static JCheckBox // my checkBoxes
    static JTextField // my textfields

    public double //declaration of my variables

    public clazz()
    {
        setSize(1600,900);
        setTitle("Project");
        setLayout(null);

        // created and set up lots of buttons/labels/textfields etc.

        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
            Button1();}});  

         button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
            Button2();}});  


         // and it continues like that

     }

public void Button1()
{
    //sth
}
public void Button2()
{
    //sth
}

// and continues like that



public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    clazz aplication = new clazz();
    aplication.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    aplication.setVisible(true);    
}
}
```

For the purpose of my question lets say button3 will be the one which creates chart (in another frame). What should I do to get a new frame with a chart based on data genereated by previous buttons. All other topics I saw do the chart using a new class and those which are not are to complicated for me (I'm a fish).

Thanks for every help!

**EDIT**

DONE IT! If you know easier ways I am interested.

```
// the beginning is the same

// to the last button in the constructor (let's say the third one) I've added method chartt()

// here's the method chartt()
 public void chartt() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        XYSeries DATA = new XYSeries("");
        matrix1 = new double[641];
        matrix2 = new double[641];
        for (int x=0; x<=640; x++)
        {
            matrix1[x]= pressure(x*1000);  //pressure is defined in another method with argument x
            matrix2[x] = x;
        }

        for (int y=0;y<=640;y++)
        {
            DATA.add(matrix2[y], matrix1[y]); 
        }


        XYDataset xyDataset = new XYSeriesCollection(DATA);
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(
        "", "", "",
        xyDataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);

        ChartPanel cp = new ChartPanel(chart) 
        {


            public Dimension getPreferredSize() 
            {
                return new Dimension(600, 600);
            }
        };

        cp.setMouseWheelEnabled(true);
        add(cp);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        frame.add(cp);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
```

Good luck to everybody!

Comment: You could structure your code better by having the different buttons generated by methods. For example: `button3.addActionListener( getButton3Listener() )`

Comment: Ok. Will try it but I still have problems to make any variable global so when I make another method that has a variable from another one I get an error (I've tried to use _final_ ahead of  for ex. _double x = 10.0; _ but it didn't work for me. Best!

Comment: *"If my question is written in a wrong way.."* What 'question'? Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39976672/edit) & add a `?` to the end of it.

Comment: question/problem/task/goal/aim you name it

Comment: I've improved my code way way better (thanks Gikkman). Will be very gladfull to have this problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I get from your question is that when you hit the last button, another JFrame(Probably you had already designed it) lets name that XYZ has to be shown.
XYZ will contain a chart designed by you.

so on the `ActionPerformed` event you need to write the following code :

```
XYZ x = new XYZ();
x.setVisible(true);
this.dispose();   // use this line if you wish to close the first frame with buttons.
```

Hope it helps. If there is something else you're asking about, please mention it in the comments.

Comment: Here's the thing. I haven't designed this another frame, I haven't even made a chart. I just don't know how to do this inside a class which is already a frame. So far I can only make one frame in class that extends from JFrame and also can make charts that extends from ApplicationFrame or JFreeChart. But to do a frame inside a frame (inside=after clicking a button) and additionaly to make this second frame to be a chart - impossible for me. So that's why I need help.